# Negate a string method in a lambda function gives error

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I am calling the string method "contains" in a lambda function, and would like to negate it. I thought this could be done with `not myString.Contains("abbr")` but it gives me the error

```ml
Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized
```

My actual function is this

```ml
open System.IO

let createWordArray filePath =
    File.ReadLines(filePath)
    |> Seq.filter (fun line -> line <> "")
    |> Seq.filter (fun line -> not line.Contains("abbr.")) // Error occurs here
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split(' ').[0])
    |> Seq.filter (fun word -> word.StartsWith("-") || word.EndsWith("-"))
    |> Seq.toArray
```

Please point out any other obvious mistakes I'm making.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add parentheses around the argument of the `not` function:

```
|> Seq.filter (fun line -> 
     not (line.Contains("abbr.")))
```

Without the parentheses, the compiler is interpreteing your code as a call to `not` with two arguments:

```
not (line.Contains) ("abbr.")
```

Answer (score 3):

F# syntax is not like C# (or C, or C++, or Java)

In particular, F# does *not* use parentheses for passing function arguments. Instead, F# uses whitespace for that:

```
let x = f y z
```

You are, of course, free to enclose any terms in parentheses if you wanted to indicate the order of operations, or just for aesthetic reasons:

```
let x = f (y+5) z // parens for order of operations
let x = f (y) (z) // parens just for the heck of it
```

So you see, when you write:

```
line.Contains("abbr.")
```

There is no special meaning to the parens. You could just as well write this:

```
line.Contains "abbr."
```

It would be equivalent.

See what's happening? Not yet? Well, ok, let's try to add the `not` to the mix:

```
not line.Contains "abbr."
```

Is it clearer now? This looks like you're trying to call the `not` function, and you're giving it two arguments: first argument is `line.Contains`, and the second argument is `"abbr."`

This is not what you meant, right? What you meant was probably to first call `line.Contains` passing it `"abbr "` as argument, and then pass the result of that to `not`

The most straightforward way to do this is to use parentheses to indicate the order of operations:

```
not (line.Contains "abbr.")
```

Or, alternatively, you could use operator `<|`, which is intended specifically for this kind of thing. It just passes a parameter to a function, so pretty much does nothing. But its point is that it's an operator, so it's precedence is lower than a function call:

```
not <| line.Cobtains "abbr."
```

Comment: Or you can write `line.Contains "abbr." |> not`, which I often find more in line of how we read the text in English.